# Getting [object, Object] when printing JSON object from req.body to the console

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, object

I'm trying to add a product's detail into my API's PostgreSQL database using Postman but when I print the values of the `specs` key to the console, I get [object Object] instead of the whole data, so even in my PostgreSQL jsonb column the data is stored as [object, Object].

```
const createProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { name, description, quantity, price, img_url, specs } = req.body;
  
  // Results in [object Object]
  console.log(specs);

  try {
    await db.query(insertProduct, [
      name,
      description,
      quantity,
      price,
      img_url,
      specs,
    ]);

    res.status(201).json({ message: "Product Added Successfully" });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    next(err);
  }
};
```

This is the json object that is being added in Postman:

```
{
    "name": "Samsung GALAXY Note II",
    "description": "Samsung Galaxy Note II sports a slightly bigger, 5.5-inch display, a quad-core processor that gets rid of the slight lag in the original Note, and best of all Android 4.1 Jelly Bean right out of the box.",
    "quantity": 10,
    "price": 249.99,
    "img_url": "www.google.com/sexyjutso",
    "specs": {
        "display": [
            {
                "size": "5.5",
                "resolution": "1280 x 720"
            }
        ],
        "camera": [
            {
                "photo": "8 MP",
                "video": "1080p"
            }
        ],
        "hardware": [
            {
                "ram": "2GB",
                "chipset": "Exynos 4412 Quad"
            }
        ],
        "battery": "3100mAh",
        "colors": [
            "Titanium Gray",
            "Marble White",
            "Amber Brown"
        ]
    }
}
```

**I even tried stringifying the `specs` but that too returns [object, Object].**

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Hey there! Have you used the body-parser package in your app file? You can see more information here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser. This should parse your request body as JSON, even if provided with nested values, thus allowing you to gather those values accordingly. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: There's no point `stringify`ing a string. I'm assuming you are using `bodyParser`? You should check the raw body of your request.

Comment: @AmitMarajand Yes, I am using the json body parser.

Comment: @MinusFour I indeed am using `bodyParser` in `app.use(express.json())`.

Comment: And have you checked the raw response? Make sure there's no `{ specs: "[object Object]" }`

Comment: @MinusFour Well that's actually the main problem here since it is getting stored in the database as `[object, Object]` when trying to stringify it (If I don't stringify it, I get the `invalid input syntax for type json` error from postgres - the `specs` column is of `jsonb` data type).

Comment: what's your middleware look like? do you only have the `express.json` im trying to replicate and everything is fine, so you must have something getting in the way before reaching your controller.

Comment: @DylanL. I have both `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded({ extended: true })`.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `express-validator` and that was sanitizing the `specs` by `trimming` and `escaping` its values and completely messing up the JSON object.

Removing that part fixed the frustrating problem.